# Better approaches than using $broadcast to update input in directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Currently I have a list of contacts on controller A. When I click on one of the contacts, it is broadcasting the contact info to **controller B** and to the datepicker directive in **controller B**. This is working but is there a better way to update the input on the datepicker directive?

```js
app.directive('datePickerDirective', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            datepickerNgModel: '=',
            datepickerId: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'Content/app/directives/templates/DatePicker.html',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            $scope.$watch(function () {
                ngModel.$setViewValue($scope.datepickerNgModel);
                return ngModel.$modelValue;
            });

            $scope.$on('data-from-component-a', function (event, data) {
                $('#' + $scope.datepickerId).val(data.date);
            })
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using events (`$broadcast`) here. You can do it by using a nice factory which handles the data for your components. You did not gave any information about your datepicker and controllers, so I created an abstract example which delivers you the basic handling.

**> Share data via factory between controllers -  [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jveaLq9p/)**

### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="publishData()">
    Publish data
  </button>
  <button ng-click="resetData()">
    Reset data
  </button>
</div>
<div ng-controller="MyOtherCtrl">
  <my-directive my-model="data.getData()"></my-directive>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, myFactory) {

  $scope.publishData = function() {
    myFactory.publishData();
  }

  $scope.resetData = function() {
    myFactory.resetData();
  }
});

myApp.controller('MyOtherCtrl', function($scope, myFactory) {
  $scope.data = myFactory;
});


myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '{{myModel}}',
      scope: {
        myModel: '='
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch('myModel', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log(newValue);
            // $('#' + $scope.datepickerId).val(newValue);
          });
      }
    }
});

myApp.factory('myFactory', function() {
  return {
    contactInfo: '',

    publishData: function() {
      this.contactInfo = 'Sdfsdfsdf';
    },

    resetData: function() {
      this.contactInfo = null;
    },

    getData: function () {
      return this.contactInfo;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow this is a much better and cleaner solution. I didn't know the factory would preserve the contactInfo data in the factory so the second controller can use it.